# How to create dynamic checkbox option based on drop-down selection?

Tags: xml, orbeon, xforms

For example, based on the country, I need to show a checkbox to select. I am facing a problem while implementing it in a repeated grid, any suggestions? The Below code would be in repeated section and will be populated based on the country selection.

```
<xf:select id="check1-control" appearance="full" bind="check1-bind">
                                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/check1/label"/>
                                    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/check1/hint"/>
                                    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                        
                        
                       <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/check1/item">
                                        <xf:label ref="label"/>
                                        <xf:value ref="value"/>
                                        <xf:hint ref="hint"/>
                                    </xf:itemset>
                                </xf:select>
```

Comment: Is this for a form created with Form Builder? What version of Orbeon Forms are you using? Is this working for you if you do it outside of a repeat?

Comment: @avernet: Yeah above is working fine outside repated grid.

Comment: Got it; what version of Orbeon Forms are you on? I am asking, because I think this didn’t use to work in now ancient versions of the product, maybe pre-4.5. If you’re seeing this is with a recent version, could create a minimal example reproducing the problem, say using Mocky.io for the service, and attach it to your question?

Comment: We are using **orbeon-4.8.1.201502021959-PE-hybris**. So, in addition, to question if we have multiple grids in repeated grid and select country from any one grid it is updating state checkbox for all grids with same data.

Comment: So I would think it should work with 4.8. Could you create a minimal example that shows the problem, and that I can run here to see what you’re referring to? And the same holds for the repeated grid / checkbox issue: could create another minimal example I can run here to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @avernet, I have created a dynamic checkbox in orbeon demo form builder. [link to the example in form builder](http://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/b057ab86d42e235c35de414595b389b8990d7dbf). The problem is with the orbeon version we are currently using.

Comment: We have checked it in version **orbeon-4.10.2.201703200524-PE** and found the same issue. But The form works fine in orbeon demo form builder. [link to example](http://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/b057ab86d42e235c35de414595b389b8990d7dbf)

Comment: So based on your testing it seems that the problem has been fixed since Orbeon Forms 4.10. Would you be able to upgrade to a recent version of Orbeon Forms, say 2017.1?

Comment: Not too sure about upgrading version, because it is the final stage of a project. We have a workaround for this.

Comment: Workaround for now is,

`We have dropdown(option1, option2, option3) and hidden checkboxes for all options.
if option1 selected then show checkbox1 option1
else if option2 selected then show checkbox2 option2
else if  option3 selected then show checkbox3 option3 `

Comment: Got it, I understand that based on timing and other factors, it isn't always easy to upgrade. And I'm glad you found a workaround. So, in the meantime, for now, I'll post an answer below to say that this issue is fixed in recent releases of the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in recent releases, and if you're encountering this, my recommendation is to upgrade. (And if you're looking for more details on this, feel free to go through the comments on the above question.)